# atd creates too many empty task files and hogs cpu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, task

There are empty task files in the `atd` task directory (`/var/spool/cron/atspool`), causing `atd` to hog CPU and fill up `syslog` too quickly!

(When atd encounters an empty file it massively spams syslog with messages such as the following (200 per second on a small arm processor):

```
atd[3410]: File a0011601410541 is in wrong format - aborting
```

Removing the empty files and restarting `atd` will bring the system to normal state. But, want to know if there is any way to prevent this from happening.

There are many forums where this seems to be discussed, but no solutions,
Does anyone know how to fix this, or any workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Remove at, if you don't use it.

```
dpkg --purge at
```

Comment: I am using `at` tasks, but that is very infrequent. So, cannot remove `atd`